# Converters, sending a String and returning a int

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, mahapps.metro

I have this converter below that should return the width of a `TextBox` according to the number of characters inside:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(String), typeof(int))]
public class TextToWidth:IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    String g = (String)value;
    return  g.Length*10;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    return null;
  }
}
```

In the ColumnDefinition of a grid, I tried to use this converter, but received an error that 
The TypeConverter for `IValueConverter` does not support converting from a string. I know that `Controls:TextboxHelper.Label` is a String:

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="{TemplateBinding Controls:TextboxHelper.Label, Converter=ToWidth}"/>
```

Why did this happen and is there any solution?

Comment: Is that the exact error you are getting? Please copy and paste the error if it is not. Is `TextboxHelper.Label` a `string` or is it a control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just change this line:

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="{TemplateBinding Controls:TextboxHelper.Label, Converter=ToWidth}"/>
```

To:

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="{TemplateBinding Controls:TextboxHelper.Label, Converter={StaticResource ToWidth}}"/>
```